# Сколько занимает процесс модерации приложения Wondows Phone в Microsoft Store?

Tags: windows-phone-8, microsoft-store

Нужно ли заранее получить какие-либо сертификаты?

Если у меня сегдоня есть готовое приложение WP, то через какое время приложение сможет быть опубликовано в сторе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правило, этот процесс отправки завершается в течение нескольких часов, хотя в некоторых случаях может занять более длительное время.

Более подробно [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt148554.aspx).

Сертификаты создаются прямо перед отправкой внутри dev центра, меньше 5 минут на это требуется.